# Instagram OAuth 2.0 authorize (register redirect URI). Should I register WWW.* version of URI also?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, authorization, instagram

I have a Web application which uses authorization via different social network account (i.e.Instagram). I created my account in Instagram, registered my Website URI (i.e. MyApplication.com) and stored secret tokens in .config file.
Every time user logs in I use these tokens. Everything works fine until user visited www.MyApplication.com.

According to [Instagram developers API](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) page ***www.MyApplication.com*** and ***MyApplication.com***  are different sites. Do I have to register WWW version of my site?
This requires to use another token pair. Thus, I have to check user authorization request twice!!! But it's not a normal solution.

Any ideas to do that much clear?

Comment: In your DNS settings point MyApplication.com to www.MyApplication.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`www.MyApplication.com` and `MyApplication.com` are different.
More or less the `www.` is just a convention.

It's a subdomain just like `app.MyApplication.com`, `images.Myapplication.com` ect.

You wouldn't register both of them.  Instead you would set up on your sever to either redirect `www.MyApplication.com` to `MyApplication.com`, or the other way around, and redirect `MyApplication.com` to `www.MyApplication.com`.

This way you only have to deal with one of them.  In your case it sounds like you'd just want to redirect everything with `www.` to just the regular domain name.

If you're interested in the debates between www. or not.

http://no-www.org/

http://www.yes-www.org/

There is an easy way to handle this your web.config.  Mads Kristensen has it covered pretty well here.

http://madskristensen.net/post/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain

Comment: :) Thanks, Kyle. I don't want to discuss this question. I'd better do much more interesting stuff.